# Suddenly, phpmyadmin doesn't work and I can't really understand why - logs look okay to me

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I've just got into PHP, Laravel and I'm using XAMPP with them.

I had started the MySQL service from XAMPP, and PHPMyAdmin was working fine. Then, using those env (into Laravel) settings I started the server (php artisan serve) and I got an error, something like 'the database seven doesn't exist' (I can't see it because I restarted my computer).

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=seven
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Now Phpmyadmin doesn't work anymore. I get "unable to connect - Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost" and I have no idea why.

Here's mysql_error.log:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300692
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.18 started; log sequence number 300701; transaction id 193
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-03-23 21:32:28 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Is apache running?

Comment: @tkausl no. I didn't know it had to. At first, I started apache and mysql, then I realised I might not need Apache and closed it. Now it works. You can add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it asap :)

Comment: It's unclear. Are you saying your Laravel application doesn't work or the phpMyAdmin application doesn't work? Both of them require Apache and MySQL server running in the background

Comment: @Dharman phpMyAdmin didn't work. I've just said the context. I didn't know I had to also use apache.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your apache and mysql is running in the XAMPP control panel